# Webdriverio unable to lauch appium service shows error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4723

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

Webdriverio unable to lauch appium service shows error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4723. Following is the configuration setup using webdriverio running appium service.

```
capabilities: [
      {
        maxInstances: 1,
        browserName: 'safari',
        automationName: 'Appium',
        deviceName: 'iPhone',
        app: 'com.apple.mobilesafari',
        udid: 'xxxxxxx',
        deviceOrientation: 'portrait',
        platformVersion: '12.1',
        platformName: 'iOS',
        automationName: 'XCUITest'
      }
    ],



    Services: ['selenium-standalone', 'appium'],
    appium: {
    args: {
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    commandTimeout: '17200',
    sessionOverride: true,
    debugLogSpacing: true,
    showIosLog: true,
    nativeInstrumentsLib: true,
    isolateSimDevice: true,
    }
      },
      port: 4723
```

Comment: Can you please try it after changing the address parameter with '0.0.0.0:4723'

Comment: localhost:4723 should work. Please check if 4723 port is not blocked in your pc

Answer (score 0):

Before running config.js you must run the appium server with 127.0.0.1 and port 4723